# Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction

Tags: mysql, sql

I get the bottom error in the debug file. I don't know how can I solve it!

```
خطای Lock wait timeout exceeded; try restarting transaction در پایگاه‌داده وردپرس برای دستور INSERT INTO `wp_options` (`option_name`, `option_value`, `autoload`) VALUES ('_transient_doing_cron', '1605081794.3521389961242675781250', 'yes') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE `option_name` = VALUES(`option_name`), `option_value` = VALUES(`option_value`), `autoload` = VALUES(`autoload`) ساخته شده توسط require('wp-blog-header.php'), require_once('wp-load.php'), require_once('wp-config.php'), require_once('wp-settings.php'), do_action('init'), WP_Hook->do_action, WP_Hook->apply_filters, wp_cron, spawn_cron, set_transient, add_option
```

Comment: are you using any plugins?

Comment: @VivekTamrakar yes, Yoast, Autoptimize

Comment: did you turn those plugins off to identify the cause?